# Sms backup in Archive mode

Tags: android, sms

I am creating backup of inbox in "sms.xml" file and I have 100 messages in inbox.

Now I have 105 sms in my inbox, now I want to take backup of only that 5 latest messages in same file. As like in Archive mode.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please post the code you've already.

Comment: brother m just access inbox and place that into xml file thats it, if u can help me then tell me , how i access only nest 5 messages, other work i will do

Comment: @kamal Show me the query that you use to get the inbox messages. You will have to modify it and select only the new messages probably based on the timestamp of the last message you have.

Comment: ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
     Cursor messagesCursor = cr.query(uri, new String[] { }, null, null, null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As u know the table structure of sms table, it contains the text msg with the timestamp value.

So u can query the Content provider for values greater than the last timestamp already present in the table.

Steps to be followed,

1. Query the latest timestamp that is archived.
2. Query the Content provider by suitable changing the `selection` parameter

By following the example http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html u can get the usage of selection param in content provider

Siva

## Update 1

```
private static final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
String last_archived_date = xxxxxxxxxxxxx;
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "date >"+last_archived_date, null, null);
```

There are many ways to retain monitor last_archived_date i prefer SharedPreference
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: in this article , i do not find how i query with time interval, how i compare it with last time interval

Comment: k on it, then plz help me, i do not try this , but when i will work on it then plz help me in this....thanx